# Getting file name from a list

Tags: linux, file

So here is what i do already,

i have a abc.txt which contains list of files.Am using abc.txt to
move those files to a folder , tar that folder and finally i download the tar to local pc from server(linux).

it goes like

```
1.abc.txt
2.abc.txt(files) -> folder
3.Folder -> folder.tar
4.folder.tar -> local pc.
```

Now i need to change this like below,

if abc.txt contains 2 files namely,

```
example1.css
example2.css
```

i need to download those files from abc.txt seperately and directly to local pc ,

since ftp or sftp need the file name to download it how can i read that 
from abc.txt.

Please help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107122/getting-file-name-from-a-lsit

Answer (score 1):

I think the hub of your problem is how to extract the correct files from your list for your subsequent two logic paths.

```
 egrep 'example1.css|example2.css' abc.txt
```

will give you all lines that match the exceptions, and

```
egrep -v 'example1.css|example2.css' abc.txt
```

will give you all lines that don't match the exceptions